# Composer: How to recursively autoload subfolders in /src

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm writing some tests for a composer package, but i cannot load classes in subfolders of /src.

My folder structure

```
root
 - src
   - file1.php
   - folder1
     - folder2
       - file2.php
 - tests
```

The tests' folder structure reflects the one of src.

In my composer.json i've:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Namespace1\\\Package_Namespace\\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when i launch the tests, only the ones in src can well include their own classes, while the ones that use the classes in subfolders can't (for example, file2.php is never loaded).

I've tried also to explicitly specify the subfolders in composer.json file, but it seems not working.

I hope someone can help me. If you need more info, please let me know and i'll provide them.

Thank you and i wish you a merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the way Composer loads psr-4 maps.

Infact i've changed namespace reflecting the folder structure and now all work well.

I think namespace can be different from folder structure, but this doesn't work.

I cannot better explain my solution, but only that reflecting the folder structure works. Is it a casuality? Mah!

Anyway, it now works...

Comment: its just { "psr-4": { "src\\": "app/src" } } and now each file in that folder should have a name space that start with `src/` ,example `namespace src\folder1\folder2` and when calling the file it will be `use src\folder1\folder2\file2`

Comment: Yes, but i don't want a namespace that starts with "src". I want a namespace that starts with my custom name...

Comment: You can prefix your classes with a base namespace or namespaces that corresponds to the base directory (ie `src`) that your files live in, but your file / directory structure must match your namespace structure to be loaded via PSR-4 (see PSR4 Sec3 p1-2).

Comment: Hi AlpineCoder, thanks for your comment: it was my solution! The folder structure was wrong! I was looking for a confirmation of this (i supposed it) and you give me it.

Post this solution as Answer and i will choose it as best answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to escape the namespace in the config:

`"autoload": { "psr-4": { "Namespace1\\Package_Namespace\\": "src" } }`

and make sure your classes / filenames follow [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Also, be sure PHPUnit / whatever test suite you're running loads the composer autoload file.

ETA:

You can also manually add your tests to the namespace in the bootstrap.php file (if you're using one for your tests):

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
$loader->addPsr4('Namespace1\\Package_Namespace\\', __DIR__.'/testdir');
```

Obviously you'll need to adjust the above accordingly to your paths.

Comment: Hi AlpineCoder, thanks for your reply.

The code is wrong represented due to the escaping of Stackoverflow when someone subit his comment. I've fixed adding another backslash. In the code the namespace is escaped as you suggested.

I think it's more something related to the inclusion process. Reading around in the Internet, it seems that is possibile to specify better how Composer has to import files and how it has to read folder but i'm not able to find a good solution.

Comment: More, the tests are all loaded correctly. Only the corresponding tested classes are not, so the test says it cannot find the tested class. This is why i'm supposing that is something related to the inclusion process. Also dumping included files with var_dump(get_included_classes()) the classes i need are not lised (ie, the one in file2.php).

Comment: Are you requiring your composer (`vendor/autoload.php') file in your test bootstrap (see line 1 of the example above)?